# Filter reactive dataset in shiny R

Tags: r, filter, shiny

I am trying to filter a reactive dataset based on different factors. However, I have some difficulties to update my dataset based on how the user filter the data. Below is a subset of the dataset I am using as well as the ui and server files I use to create the shiny Ap.

**Load package**

```
  library (shiny)
    library(ggvis)
    library(dplyr)
```

**The dataframe I use:**

```
 Flux_Data_df<- structure(list(Site_ID = structure(c(1L, 3L, 5L, 7L, 8L), .Label = c("AR-Slu", 
"AR-Vir", "AU-Tum", "AU-Wac", "BE-Bra", "BE-Jal", "BE-Vie", "BR-Cax", 
"BR-Ma2", "BR-Sa1", "BR-Sa3", "BW-Ma1", "CA-Ca1", "CA-Ca2", "CA-Ca3", 
"CA-Gro", "Ca-Man", "CA-NS1", "CA-NS2", "CA-NS3", "CA-NS4", "CA-NS5", 
"CA-NS6", "CA-NS7", "CA-Oas", "CA-Obs", "CA-Ojp", "CA-Qcu", "CA-Qfo", 
"CA-SF1", "CA-SF2", "CA-SF3", "CA-SJ1", "CA-SJ2", "CA-SJ3", "CA-TP1", 
"CA-TP2", "CA-TP3", "CA-TP4", "CA-Wp1", "CN-Bed", "CN-Cha", "CN-Din", 
"CN-Ku1", "CN-Qia", "CZ-Bk1", "De-Bay", "DE-Hai", "DE-Har", "DE-Lkb", 
"DE-Meh", "DE-Obe", "DE-Tha", "DE-Wet", "DK-Sor", "ES-Es1", "FI-Hyy", 
"FI-Sod", "FR-Fon", "FR-Hes", "FR-Lbr", "FR-Pue", "GF-Guy", "ID-Pag", 
"IL-Yat", "IS-Gun", "IT-Col", "IT-Cpz", "IT-Lav", "IT-Lma", "IT-Noe", 
"IT-Non", "IT-Pt1", "IT-Ro1", "IT-Ro2", "IT-Sro", "JP-Tak", "JP-Tef", 
"JP-Tom", "MY-Pso", "NL-Loo", "PA-Spn", "PT-Esp", "RU-Fyo", "RU-Skp", 
"RU-Zot", "SE-Abi", "SE-Fla", "SE-Nor", "SE-Sk1", "SE-Sk2", "SE-St1", 
"UK-Gri", "UK-Ham", "US-Bar", "US-Blo", "US-Bn1", "US-Bn2", "Us-Bn3", 
"US-Dk2", "US-Dk3", "US-Fmf", "US-Fuf", "US-Fwf", "US-Ha1", "US-Ha2", 
"US-Ho1", "US-Ho2", "US-Lph", "US-Me1", "US-Me3", "US-Me4", "US-Me6", 
"US-Moz", "US-NC1", "US-Nc2", "US-NR1", "US-Oho", "US-So2", "US-So3", 
"US-Sp1", "US-Sp2", "US-Sp3", "US-Syv", "US-Umb", "US-Wbw", "US-Wcr", 
"US-Wi0", "US-Wi1", "US-Wi2", "US-Wi4", "US-Wi8", "VU-Coc", "CA-Cbo", 
"CN-Lao", "ID-Buk", "JP-Fuj", "RU-Ab", "RU-Be", "RU-Mix"), class = "factor"), 
    Ecosystem = structure(c(5L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 3L), .Label = c("DBF", 
    "DNF", "EBF", "ENF", "MF", "SHB", "WSA"), class = "factor"), 
    Climate = structure(c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L), .Label = c("Arid", 
    "Continental", "Temperate", "Tropical"), class = "factor"), 
    Management = structure(c(4L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("High", 
    "Low", "Moderate", "None"), class = "factor"), Stand_Age = c(50, 
    99, 77.0833333333333, 66.2, 97), NEP = c(1262.24986565392, 
    251.665998718498, 89.590110051402, 467.821910494384, 560), 
    GPP = c(2437.9937774539, 1837.82835206203, 1353.91140903122, 
    1740.68843840394, 3630), NEP_GPP = c(0.517741217113419, 0.143353622997247, 
    0.0760076059028116, 0.270737440100469, 0.1542699725), Uncert = c(7.29706486170583, 
    12.3483066698996, 7.59406340226036, 8.2523670901841, 12.1
    ), Gap_filled = c(0.953310527540233, 0.969648973753497, 0.9395474605477, 
    0.923408280276339, 1), MAT = c(19.0438821722383, 9.67003296799878, 
    10.7728316162948, 8.2796213684244, 27.341666667), MAT_An = c(-0.0413522012578611, 
    0.840055031446541, 0.705896226415094, 0.805524109014675, 
    0.191666666666667), MAT_Trend = c(0.0119577487502016, 0.0196238509917756, 
    0.0305871364833632, 0.0381007095629741, 0.0194619147449338
    ), MAP = c(351.700001291931, 1107.49999958277, 844.158499979666, 
    998.205467054248, 2279.5), MAP_CRU = c(592.2, 850.925, 852.591666666667, 
    1098.98, 2279.5), SPI_CRU_Mean = c(-0.352735702252502, 0.188298093749456, 
    0.0830157542916604, 0.397632136136383, 1.31028809089487), 
    MAP_An = c(4.14188988095238, -15.8198660714286, 5.39074900793651, 
    2.28799107142857, 1.55565476190476), MAP_Trend = c(1.38787584993337, 
    0.147192657259031, 0.747167885331603, 0.104885622031644, 
    0.841903850753408), CEC_Total_1km = c(14.05, 10.25, 17.975, 
    21, 9.95), Clay_Silt = c(36.65, 42.125, 32.275, 55, 54.825
    ), Clay_1km = c(26.425, 31.425, 11.25, 22.45, 38.075), Silt_1km = c(10.225, 
    10.7, 21.025, 32.55, 16.75), Sand_1km = c(63.35, 57.325, 
    67.65, 45, 45.275), NOy = c(1.73752826416889, 2.76055219091326, 
    4.96187381895543, 5.06857284157762, 0.90948457442513), NHx = c(2.50363534311763, 
    2.99675999696687, 11.2747222582845, 13.9207300067467, 1.53292533883169
    ), Soil_C_1km = c(3.6, 17, 23.575, 26.65, 8.15), Lat = c(-33.4648, 
    -35.6566, 51.3092, 50.3051, -1.72000003), Long = c(-66.4598, 
    148.1516, 4.5206, 5.9981, -51.4500008)), .Names = c("Site_ID", 
"Ecosystem", "Climate", "Management", "Stand_Age", "NEP", "GPP", 
"NEP_GPP", "Uncert", "Gap_filled", "MAT", "MAT_An", "MAT_Trend", 
"MAP", "MAP_CRU", "SPI_CRU_Mean", "MAP_An", "MAP_Trend", "CEC_Total_1km", 
"Clay_Silt", "Clay_1km", "Silt_1km", "Sand_1km", "NOy", "NHx", 
"Soil_C_1km", "Lat", "Long"), row.names = c(NA, 5L), class = "data.frame")
```

**Choose x and y variable to choose**

```
axis_vars <- c(
  "NEP observed [gC.m-2.y-1]" = "NEP",
  "NEP predicted [gC.m-2.y-1]" = "prediction",
  "CUEe" = "NEP_GPP",
  "GPP [gC.m-2.y-1]" = "GPP",
  "Forest Age [years]" = "Stand_Age",
  "MAT [°C]" = "MAT",
  "SPI" = "SPI_CRU_Mean",
  "MAP [mm.y-1]" = "MAP",
  "MAP trend [mm.y-1]" = "MAP_Trend",
  "MAT tremd [°C.y-1]" = "MAT_Trend",
  "Clay content [kg.kg-1]" = "Clay_1km",
  "N deposition [kg N.ha-1.y-1]" = "NHx"
)
```

## Update

**The ui file:**

```
  ui<-  shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Data exploration"),
  p('Interactive tool for data exploration'),
  em('by, ', a('Simon Besnard',  href = 'http://www.bgc-jena.mpg.de/bgi/index.php/People/SimonBesnard')),

  fluidRow(
    column(4,
           wellPanel(
             h4("Filter data"),

             sliderInput("Gap_Filled", "Fraction gap filling", 0, 1, value = c(0, 1)),
             sliderInput("Uncert", "Uncertainties", 0, 45, value = c(0, 45),
                         step = 1),
             sliderInput("GPP", "GPP [gC.m-2.y-1]", 0, 4000, value = c(0, 4000),
                         0, 4000, 4000, step = 100),
             checkboxGroupInput("Management", "Intensity of management",  c("None", "Low", "Moderate", "High"),
                                selected= c("None", "Low", "Moderate", "High"), inline = T),
             checkboxGroupInput("Disturbance", "Type of disturbance",
                         c("Afforestation\\Reforestation", "Harvest", "None", "Wildfire"),
                         selected = c("Afforestation\\Reforestation", "Harvest", "None", "Wildfire"), inline=T),
             checkboxGroupInput("Climate", "Type of climate",
                                     c("Arid", "Continental", "Temperate", "Tropical"),
                                selected=c("Arid", "Continental", "Temperate", "Tropical"), inline=T),
             checkboxGroupInput("Ecosystem",
                          label="PFTs",
                          choices=list("DBF", "DNF", "EBF", "ENF", "MF",  "SHB"),
                          selected=c("DBF", "DNF", "EBF", "ENF", "MF","SHB"), inline=T)
           ),

    wellPanel(
             selectInput("xvar", "X-axis variable", axis_vars, selected = "Stand_Age"),
             selectInput("yvar", "Y-axis variable", axis_vars, selected = "NEP")
             )),

  column(8,
    tabsetPanel(
      tabPanel("Bokeh Plot", ggvisOutput("rBokeh"))
    ))
)))
```

**And the server file:**

```
 server<- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

# Apply filters
FLux_Data <- reactive({
  gap_filled<- input$Gap_filled
  uncert<- input$Uncert
  gpp<- input$GPP
  management<- input$Management
  disturbance <- input$Disturbance
  climate <- input$Climate
  ecosystem <- input$Ecosystem

  m<- Flux_Data_df %>%
      filter(
        gap_filled >= Gap_filled &
        uncert >= Uncert &
        gpp >= GPP &
        management >= Management &
        disturbance %in% Disturbance &
        climate %in% Climate &
        ecosystem %in% Ecosystem
      )
  m <- as.data.frame(m)
  m
    })

# Function for generating tooltip text
Site_tooltip <- function(x) {
  if (is.null(x)) return(NULL)
  if (is.null(x$Site_ID)) return(NULL)

  # Pick out the movie with this ID
  df <- isolate(FLux_Data())
  Flux_ID <- df[df$Site_ID == x$Site_ID, ]
  paste0("<b>", Flux_ID$Site_ID, "</b><br>",
         Flux_ID$year, "<br>")
}

# A reactive expression with the ggvis plot
Bokeh <- reactive({
  # Lables for axes
  xvar_name <- names(axis_vars)[axis_vars == input$xvar]
  yvar_name <- names(axis_vars)[axis_vars == input$yvar]

  # Normally we could do something like props(x = ~BoxOffice, y = ~Reviews),
  # but since the inputs are strings, we need to do a little more work.
  xvar <- prop("x", as.symbol(input$xvar))
  yvar <- prop("y", as.symbol(input$yvar))

FLux_Data %>%
    ggvis(x = xvar, y = yvar) %>%
    layer_points(size := 50, size.hover := 200,
                 fillOpacity := 0.2, fillOpacity.hover := 0.5) %>%
    add_tooltip(Site_tooltip, "hover") %>%
    add_axis("x", title = xvar_name) %>%
    add_axis("y", title = yvar_name) %>%
    set_options(width = 500, height = 500)
})
observe({
  Bokeh %>% bind_shiny("rBokeh")
  })
})

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Basically, I would like to update my dataframe anytime a filtering action is done in the shiny app based on the filtering set-up in the ui file. I try to use the `filter` function from the `dplyr` package but could not manage to do it. Anyone can help me out with it?

Comment: The filter function should be something like `filter(Gap_filled==input$Gap_FIlled & Uncert=input$...`

Comment: By using the == it does not work. `rror in eval(substitute(expr), envir, enclos) : 
  incorrect length (0), expecting: 716`. I try to use the `%in% instead as such  `Gap_filled%in%input$Gap_FIlled & ` but the plot is not ceated in the app.

Comment: There are several issues that you need to fix: 1. For the sliderInputs, you need to use `>` or `<` or similar instead of `%in%` 2. For the selectInputs you need to make sure you options are identical to what's in your data (for example `Afforestation-Reforestation` but data are using forward slash), also might be a good idea to provide default values. 3. When you use a reactive value, use it as a function like `Bokeh()` but also enclose the line in `observe`. 4. You probably just need a ggVisOutput instead of a rbokehoutput.

Comment: 5. Don't reuse variable names for different purposes (for example `Flux_Data_df` is both your source data and the temporary name inside your site_tooltip function. 6. I had a typo (uppercase I) in my first comment which should be fixed. 7. You have an error in your ui code which causes the second `column(8` to be outside the fluidRow.

Comment: @warmoverflow. How and where would enclose the Bokeh line in `observe`?

Comment: `Bokeh() %>% bind_shiny("rBokeh")` this should be enclosed in `observe` otherwise you will get error messages.

Comment: @warmoverflow I have tried to implement all your recommendations, but I still cannot make the shiny app working. I have this error message`Warning: Error in eval: incorrect length (0), expecting: 524` Do you know what still need to be fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working version. Note that I removed many filter conditions and also the tooltip function to simplify it.

```
library(shiny)
library(ggvis)
library(dplyr)

axis_vars <- c(
    "NEP observed [gC.m-2.y-1]" = "NEP",
    "NEP predicted [gC.m-2.y-1]" = "prediction",
    "CUEe" = "NEP_GPP",
    "GPP [gC.m-2.y-1]" = "GPP",
    "Forest Age [years]" = "Stand_Age",
    "MAT [°C]" = "MAT",
    "SPI" = "SPI_CRU_Mean",
    "MAP [mm.y-1]" = "MAP",
    "MAP trend [mm.y-1]" = "MAP_Trend",
    "MAT tremd [°C.y-1]" = "MAT_Trend",
    "Clay content [kg.kg-1]" = "Clay_1km",
    "N deposition [kg N.ha-1.y-1]" = "NHx"
)

ui<- shinyUI(fluidPage(
    titlePanel("Data exploration"),
    p('Interactive tool for data exploration'),
    em('by, ', a('Simon Besnard',  href = 'http://www.bgc-jena.mpg.de/bgi/index.php/People/SimonBesnard')),

    fluidRow(
        column(3,
               wellPanel(
                   h4("Filter data"),

                   sliderInput("Gap_Filled", "Fraction gap filling", 0, 1, value = c(0, 1)),
                   sliderInput("Uncert", "Uncertainties", 0, 45, value = c(0, 45),
                               step = 1),
                   sliderInput("GPP", "GPP [gC.m-2.y-1]", 0, 4000, value = c(0, 4000),
                               0, 4000, 4000, step = 100),
                   sliderInput("Management", "Intensity of management", 0, 3, value = c(0, 3),
                               step = 1),
                   selectInput("Disturbance", "Type of disturbance", multiple = TRUE,
                               c("Afforestation-Reforestation", "Harvest", "Undisturbed", "Wildfire")),
                   selectInput("Climate", "Type of climate", multiple = TRUE,
                               c("Arid", "Continental", "Temperate", "Tropical"), selected = c("Temperate")),
                   selectInput("Ecosystem", "PFTs", multiple = TRUE,
                               c("DBF", "DNF", "EBF", "ENF", "MF",  "SHB"), selected=c("MF"))
               ),

               wellPanel(
                   selectInput("xvar", "X-axis variable", axis_vars, selected = "Stand_Age"),
                   selectInput("yvar", "Y-axis variable", axis_vars, selected = "NEP")
               )),

    column(8,
           mainPanel(
               ggvisOutput("ggvis"))
               ))
))

server<- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

    # A reactive expression with the ggvis plot
    Bokeh <- reactive({
        # Lables for axes
        xvar_name <- names(axis_vars)[axis_vars == input$xvar]
        yvar_name <- names(axis_vars)[axis_vars == input$yvar]
        xvar <- prop("x", as.symbol(input$xvar))
        yvar <- prop("y", as.symbol(input$yvar))

    test <- Flux_Data_df %>%
        filter(
            Gap_filled > input$Gap_filled[1] &
            Gap_filled < input$Gap_filled[2]) %>% 
        filter(
            Climate %in% input$Climate &
            Ecosystem %in% input$Ecosystem
        ) %>% as.data.frame()

        test %>%
            ggvis(x = xvar, y = yvar) %>%
            layer_points(size := 50, size.hover := 200,
                         fillOpacity := 0.2, fillOpacity.hover := 0.5) %>%
            add_axis("x", title = xvar_name) %>%
            add_axis("y", title = yvar_name) %>%
            set_options(width = 500, height = 500)
    })

    observe({
        Bokeh() %>% bind_shiny("ggvis")
    })
})

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Any ideas how I can set up the filter for the slide bar in the server. For instance, `Gap_filled >= input$Gap_filled &` does not work.

Comment: sliderInput returns two values (min, max), so you need to do `Gap_filled >= input$Gap_filled[1] & Gap_filled < input$Gap_filled[2]`

Comment: Yeah I tried it already and I have the same error message `Error in eval: incorrect length (0), expecting: 524`

Comment: That is strange. I updated my answer with a sliderInput filter and it works on my computer. Test it with the first slider. Note that if there is only one or zero row left after the filter, the plot goes blank, which is likely a ggvis issue not related to this question.

Comment: Oh ok. You need to call a second filter option. Thanks a lot

Comment: @ warmoverflow Are you familiar with intergrating loop in a reactive dataframe? I have this question in the link below and thought you might have an idea why I got an error. Thanks. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37745310/create-a-loop-in-a-shiny-app-in-r