# Create a loop in a shiny app in R

Tags: r, for-loop, shiny

I would like to run a loop in my shiny app in order to compute a new variable and add it to the reactive dataframe. The `Flux_Data` is the reactive dataframe which is updated according to the user filtering. This dataframe is then use in the loop to compute a new variable. The new variable should then be added to the dataframe. I have tried to implement it in the server file but I have an error message. `Warning: Error in for: invalid for() loop sequence` Anyone knows what I am doing wrong? Let me know if you need the ui file and a subset of my original dataframe.

## Update

```
shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
    
Update_df1 <- reactive({
  
  # Lables for axes
  xvar_name <- names(axis_vars)[axis_vars == input$xvar]
  yvar_name <- names(axis_vars)[axis_vars == input$yvar]
  xvar <- prop("x", as.symbol(input$xvar))
  yvar <- prop("y", as.symbol(input$yvar))
  
  Flux_Data_df %>%
    filter(
      Gap_filled >= input$Gap_filled[1] & 
      Gap_filled <= input$Gap_filled[2] &
      Uncert > input$Uncert[1] & 
      Uncert < input$Uncert[2] &
      Stand_Age >= input$Stand_Age[1] & 
      Stand_Age <= input$Stand_Age[2] &
      GPP > input$GPP[1] & 
      GPP < input$GPP[2] &
      MAT > input$MAT[1] & 
      MAT < input$MAT[2] &
      MAP > input$MAP[1] & 
      MAP < input$MAP[2]) %>%
    filter(
      Management %in% input$Management &
      Disturbance %in% input$Disturbance &
      Climate %in% input$Climate &
      Ecosystem %in% input$Ecosystem) %>% as.data.frame()
})

# A reactive expression to add model predicion to a new dataframe
Update_df2<- reactive({
    for(id in unique(Update_df1$Site_ID)){
      lm.Age<- try(nlsLM(NEP~offset + A*(1-exp(k*Stand_Age)), data = Update_df1[Update_df1$Site_ID != id,], 
                         start = list(A=  711.5423, k= -0.2987, offset= -444.2672),
                         lower= c(A = -Inf, k =  -Inf, offset= -1500), control = list(maxiter = 500), weights = 1/Uncert), silent=TRUE);
      Update_df1$f_Age[Update_df1$Site_ID == id] <- predict(object = lm.Age, newdata = Update_df1[Update_df1$Site_ID == id,])
    } 
  
  for(id in unique(Update_df1$Site_ID)){
    lm.NEP<- lm(NEP~ (f_Age + Stand_Age + GPP)^2 +
                  Clay_1km + GPP:MAP + SPI_CRU_Mean:NHx + Stand_Age:NHx ,
                data=Update_df1[Update_df1$Site_ID != id,], weights = 1/Uncert)
    Update_df1$prediction[Update_df1$Site_ID == id] <- predict(object = lm.NEP, newdata = Update_df1[Update_df1$Site_ID == id,])
  }
})
```

Comment: You cannot chain a for loop to `%>%`. Just eliminate the `%>%` and put the data into the actual function. I don't think this is correct either `input$f_Age[input$Site_ID == id] <- Age.pred`. Also, again, you should use `Bokeh() %>% bind_shiny("ggvis")` (WITH PARENTHESIS).

Comment: @ warmoverflow I updated the script but still cannot make it work. I have this error message `Warning: Error in $: object of type 'closure' is not subsettable`. Should I call the `Update_df1` dataframe `Update_df1()` in the loop or otherwise?

Comment: Yes, whenever you use a `reactive` defined by `reactive({})`, you should add the parenthesis.

Comment: Alright. But now I have this error message `object 'Site_ID' not found`. Does it have to be defined beforehand? If so how?