# Apply a filter once from a checkbox to many reactive objects in Shiny in R

Tags: r, shiny

I am building a shiny app in R where I have a multiple checkbox at the top to filter levels of a factor. I then display various tables/plots of the filtered data.
However, in Shiny I only know how to filter each of these reactives by having to re-filter the entire data set in each reactive.
For example,

Data set > Filter > Construct Table 1

Data set > Filter > Construct Table 2

...

Data set > Filter > Construct Table N

Instead, I would like to have a way to run the filter only once for efficiency. E.g.

Data set > Filter > Construct Table 1, ..., N.

Is this possible?
I've given a small sample code using `mtcars` and creating just one plot and one table from a filtered multiple checkbox.

```
#install.packages(c("shiny", "shinythemes", "shinyjs", "plotly", "shinydashboard"))

library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)
library(shinyjs)
library(plotly)
library(shinydashboard)

data(mtcars)

ui <- dashboardPage(skin = "blue",
                    dashboardHeader(title = "Stack Overflow Example"),
                    
                    sidebar = dashboardSidebar(),
                    
                    dashboardBody(
                                fluidRow(
                                  box(width = 12,
                                      checkboxGroupInput(inputId = "checkgroup",
                                                         label = "Engine to show:",
                                                         choices = c("V-shaped" = "0",
                                                                     "Straight" = "1"),
                                                         selected = c("0","1")))),
                                
                                fluidRow(
                                  box(plotlyOutput(outputId = "plot_weight", height = "240"),
                                      shiny::tableOutput("table_weight")
                                  )
                                  )
                    )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
 
  # Subset data
  selected_data <- reactive({
    mtcars_checkgroup <- mtcars %>% filter(vs %in% c((input$checkgroup)))
    return(mtcars_checkgroup)
  })

  table_weight <- reactive({
    selected_data() %>%
      summarise(mean(wt))
  }) 
  plot_weight  <- reactive({
    ggplot(selected_data(), aes(y = wt)) + geom_boxplot()
  }) 
  output$table_weight <- shiny::renderTable({(table_weight())}, striped = TRUE)
  output$plot_weight <- renderPlotly({plot_weight()})
}


shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I had a look at other issues - such as [Filter reactive dataset in shiny R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37730351/filter-reactive-dataset-in-shiny-r), but this still re-runs the filter each time the user updates

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, the filter already runs only once: in `selected_data <- reactive({...})`. shiny will automatically cache your `selected_data()` for use in all outputs.

Also, you may want to simplify the code by not using reactive intermediate statements for the outputs:

```
  output$table_weight <- renderTable(selected_data() %>%
      summarise(mean(wt)), striped = TRUE)

  output$plot_weight <- renderPlotly(ggplot(selected_data(), aes(y = wt)) 
+ geom_boxplot())
```

Comment: Interesting! It is running a lot slower for me when I have several tables/plots that call the filtered item, compared to if I just set one table as filtered. I suppose this is because it is updating several tables/plots at once? Thanks for explaining.

Comment: Maybe plotly is slow to generate an output.